# NoLinkedYouTubeAccount

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am using youtube_it for my video upload.. i downloaded the demo app for youtube_it and when i try to upload videos i get the following error `**NoLinkedYouTubeAccount**` 
my youtube_it.yml looks like this

```
common: &common
  dev_key: AI39si4aJ5Nzw2Sknaox12T14SvLip_TjPF3ZgE-JlP_YPTX_Ma3Pd2PPOPF_K9hmDYR8uouMTefSltn_ZXrWe0gFslMsESzbg
  username:  lafseries@gmail.com
  password:  password

test:
  <<: *common
development:
  <<: *common
production:
  <<: *common
```

and when i checked my google account the dev_key matched

Comment: I have same problem, did you find the answer?

Comment: @Neeraj : Go to youtube.com then login and create a channel.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include a load_youtube.rb file in your intializers folder if you haven't done.

```
require 'ostruct'
raw_config = File.read(::Rails.root.to_s + "/config/youtube_it.yml")
YouTubeITConfig =  OpenStruct.new(YAML.load(raw_config)[Rails.env])
```